# QtCreator build mode: Profile

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I've just upgraded to the latest QtCreator IDE and found out that among old two build modes {release, debug} there is a third one: Profile. Could someone point me to the explanation of difference between this new mode and the old ones?
I guess it should be related to Valgrind function profiler that usually takes Release builds only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings.html).

> A profile configuration is an optimized release build that is
>   delivered with separate debug information. It is best suited for
>   analyzing applications.

On Windows. It will create pdb alone with release version exe. Run faster and can still debug with symbols using [Just-In-Time Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-using-the-just-in-time-debugger)

Answer (score 3):

OK, it seems that this was made for QML Profiler and introduced somewhere in QtCreator 4.x.x. It builds release binaries but enables debugging for QML runtime in them. So it's something between release and debug modes. And it seems to be more or less equal to Release if you're not using QML in your app.
Would be great if someone points to official description of that new feature.

Answer (score 1):

Profile is Release-with-debug-symbols.

It is unrelated to QML.

Comment: Nice addition, so it is not only about QML. But I disagree that it's unrelated to QML. In my system Profile build adds `CONFIG+=qml_debug` to qmake effective call in `Build steps` which is due to `Enable QML debugging and profiling` got turned on.